# Function mouseup in forEach at each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have foreach loop:

```
objects.forEach(function(object) {                      
    var button = '<tr><td>' + object.object.code + '</td><td>' +
                 formatDistance(1456000) + '</td></tr>';          
    $(button).mouseup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 1) {
            runObject(object);
        }
    });
    result += button;
});

$(mydiv).html(result);
```

but this can't work. I have one object listed only in each `forEach` cycle.

How can I correctly write `onclick` event for each point of loop.

Comment: `$(button)` creates the HTML elements and those are the elements you're adding the event to. `button` is just text. You're losing the reference to the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append each item into your `div` inside the `forEach` loop:

```
objects.forEach(function(object) {                      
  var button = $('<tr><td>' + object.object.code + '</td><td>' + formatDistance(1456000) + '</td></tr>');          
  button.mouseup(function(e) { if(e.which === 1) { runObject(object); } });
  $(mydiv).append(button);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
objects.forEach(function(object) {                      
    var button = '<tr class="test_' + object.object.code + "'><td>' + object.object.code + '</td><td>' +
                 formatDistance(1456000) + '</td></tr>';          
    $('.test_' + object.object.code).mouseup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 1) {
            runObject(object);
        }
    });
    result += button;
});

$(mydiv).html(result);
```

you have to resolve syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways:

```js
//Create an empty container
var $result = $();

[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(object) {

    //Create TRs as jQuery objects (as opposed to strings), append whatever
 var $button = $('<tr/>').append('<td>[' + object + ']: </td><td>' + ("this is " + object) + '</td>');
    //Bing events, mouseup, click or whatever
    $button.on("mouseup", function(e) {
        //Add whatever conditions you like
        if (e.which === 1) {
          alert (object);
        }
    });
    //Keep adding the TR to the container
    $result = $result.add($button)
});

//Append all at once, outside the loop
$("#mydiv").empty().append($result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```